# Joomla Gantry css / less structure

Tags: css, joomla, less

I am developing a new template for joomla and decided to use the Gantry framework. The mai problem of using it, is that i don't really understand the css/less structure. I need to understand it so i can make it more dry and easy to maintain. I find different overrides in difeerent css/less files. I don't really understand the logic. Can someone explain me how the css/less is structured?
Here is the global less file:(hope this gives an ideea about the structure)

```
@import "jui/less/mixins.less";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins/index.less";

// Core and Grid
@import "gantry-core.less";
@import "joomla-core.less";

// Template core styling and layout
@import "template.less";
@import "style.less";
@import "header-@{headerstyle}.less";
@import "jui/less/font-awesome/font-awesome.less";
@import "utilities.less";
@import "prettify.less";
@import "offline.less";
@import "error.less";
@import "jui/less/bootstrap-overrides.less";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the "LESS CSS" documentation on the Gantry website? http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/advanced/less_css.md

Comment: Yes i did and found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mess, I agree. It's clearly not been authored with end-users in mind, and it certainly isn't DRY. In my experience Gantry's LESS is very badly written, demonstrating a fundamental lack of understanding about how to use pre-processors responsibly or efficiently and creating some horrible outputs in the process.

If you want lightweight and maintainable LESS you'd be better writing it yourself, from scratch.

Last template I built with Gantry I disabled their LESS compiler, removed their LESS files and dropped in my own Sass framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

The line @import "header-@{headerstyle}.less"; gives us a clue that from global.less you are able to load different themes depending on user selection in backend.

Basically you can follow the files inheritance by seeing what is being imported by each file.